# cannot set header when using express hbs render

Tags: node.js, express, header, handlebars.js

I am trying to insert a token into the response header of a post route just before the view-engine-hadlebars renders.

This is the post route that I want to set up the haeder in:

```
app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {


let email = req.body.usremail;
let password = req.body.password;


var user = new User({
    email,
    password
})
user.save().then(() => {
    return user.generateAuthToken();
}).then((token)=>{


    res.set('x-auth', token);
    res.render("project.hbs", {
        paragraph: `Welcome ${email}. What would you like to do?`,
        button1: "New poll",
        button2: "See your polls",
        button3: "See all polls",
        link1: "/newpoll",
        link2: "/yourpolls",
        link3: "/allpolls",
        pie: true,
        two: true
    })
}, (e) => {
    console.log(e.message);
})

})
```

This is the get route that I want to receive the header in:

```
loginRouter.get("/newpoll", authenticate, (req, res) => {
console.log("newpoll/get:",req.header("x-auth"));

   res.render("project.hbs", {
    paragraph: `Enter your poll question and answers then submit`,
    quessubmit: true,
    method: "post",
    action: "/newpoll",
    ques: true
})
})
```

the get route is saying it's undefined. Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your complete route code?

Comment: I have updated the code, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how headers work. When you do: `res.set('x-auth', token);` on `/signup` route, you're setting a response header, that header will be sent to the client, but won't persist to other requests.

When the user clicks on the link, and goes to `/newpoll`, there is no possible way to send a custom a HTTP header through the `a` element, so your code won't work.

What you're looking for is a cookie, that will be set on `/signup` and can be retrieved on any other route.

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
    /* ... */
    res.cookie('x-auth', token);
    /* .. */
});

loginRouter.get("/newpoll", authenticate, (req, res) => {
    console.log("newpoll/get:",req.cookies["x-auth"]);
});
```

Take a look at [res.cookie](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie) documentation, to learn how to set secure options.

**NOTE:** I do not know what your method `authenticate` does, or how are you authenticating the users, but you should probably check whether `x-auth` cookie is set or not there.

Comment: thank you, that was the functionality I was looking for. I was using the header for another project, and got thrown off since I was using postman and was able to see the headers there